# Test in VHDL of working frequency of a combinatorial component

Tags: vhdl, ise

I want to measure approximately working frequency of a combinatorial component. To do this, I use a my implementation of scan-chain to wrap my ripple carry adder. This is my code:

```
--Ripple carry wrapped using scan chain
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity ripple_carry_clocked_m is
    generic (size : integer:=8);
    Port ( data_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           data_out : out  STD_LOGIC
          );
end ripple_carry_clocked_m;

architecture Structural of ripple_carry_clocked_m is

component ripple_carry_m is
    generic (size : integer:=8);
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (size-1 downto 0);
       b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (size-1 downto 0);
       cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
       overflow : out  STD_LOGIC;
       sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (size-1 downto 0));
end component;

component scan_chain_m is
    generic(N : natural:=8; 
           right_left_n : bit:='1'); 
    Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0);
           SI : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           SE : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           clear_n : in STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in STD_LOGIC;             
           SO : out  STD_LOGIC; 
           reg_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0) 
          );
end component ;

signal s_sum: std_logic_vector (size-1 downto 0):= (others=>'0');
signal s_overflow: std_logic:= '0';
signal s_data: std_logic_vector (2*size downto 0):= (others=>'0');

begin

    IST_SCAN_CHAIN1 : scan_chain_m generic map(2*size+1,'1') port map(
          SI => data_in,
          D => (others=>'1'),
          SE => '1',
          enable => '1',
          clear_n => '1',
          clk => clock,
          SO =>open,
          reg_out => s_data);

    IST_RIPPLE_CARRY: ripple_carry_m generic map(size) port map(
          a => s_data(2*size downto size+1),
          b => s_data(size downto 1),
          cin => s_data(0),
          overflow => s_overflow,
          sum => s_sum);


    IST_SCAN_CHAIN2 : scan_chain_m generic map(size+1,'1') port map(
          SI => '0',
          D => s_overflow & s_sum,
          SE => '1',
          enable => '1',
          clear_n => '1',
          clk => clock,
          SO =>data_out,
          reg_out => open);

end Structural;
```

Scan chain code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity scan_chain_m is
    generic(N : natural:=8; -- lenght register
           right_left_n : bit:='0'); -- right shift = 1, left shift =0
    Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0); 
       SI : in  STD_LOGIC; -- bit in shifted
       SE : in  STD_LOGIC; --SE=0 register, SE=1 shift register
       clk : in  STD_LOGIC; --frequenza di lavoro
       clear_n : in STD_LOGIC; --reset register
       enable : in STD_LOGIC;             
       SO : out  STD_LOGIC; --bit out shifted
       reg_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 downto 0) 
          );
end scan_chain_m ;


architecture Structural of scan_chain_m is

component flop_m is
    Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           SI : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           SE : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clear_n : in STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC); 
end component;

signal sq : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0):=(others=>'0');

begin
    RIGHT_SHIFT : if(right_left_n='1') generate
        CHAIN_RIGHT : for k in N-2 downto 0 generate
            IST_K_RIGHT : flop_m port map(
                D => D(k),
                SI => sq(k+1),
                SE => SE,
                clk => clk,
                clear_n => clear_n,
                enable => enable,
                Q => sq(k));
        end generate CHAIN_RIGHT; 
        IST_IN_RIGHT : flop_m port map(
                D => D(N-1),
                SI => SI,
                SE => SE,
                clk => clk,
                clear_n => clear_n,
                enable => enable,
                Q => sq(N-1));
        SO <= sq(0);
        reg_out <= sq;
    end generate RIGHT_SHIFT;

    LEFT_SHIFT : if(right_left_n='0')generate
        CHAIN_LEFT : for k in 1 to N-1 generate
            IST_K_LEFT : flop_m port map(
                D => D(k),
                SI => sq(k-1),
                SE => SE,
                clk => clk,
                clear_n => clear_n,
                enable => enable,
                Q => sq(k));
        end generate CHAIN_LEFT;
        IST_IN_LEFT : flop_m port map(
                D => D(0),
                SI => SI,
                SE => SE,
                clk => clk,
                clear_n => clear_n,
                enable => enable,
                Q => sq(0));
        SO <= sq(N-1);
        reg_out <= sq;
    end generate LEFT_SHIFT;

end Structural;
```

Controlled flip-flop code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity flop_m is
    Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           SI : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           SE : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           clear_n : in STD_LOGIC; 
           enable : in STD_LOGIC; 
       Q : out  STD_LOGIC); 
end flop_m;

architecture Structural of flop_m is

component flip_flopD_m is
    Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset_n : in  STD_LOGIC;
           preset_n : in STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component mux2_1_m is
    port (a,b,sel : in std_logic;
            y : out std_logic);
end component;
signal mux_d : std_logic; --uscita del multiplexer

begin

    mux2_1 : mux2_1_m port map(
        a => D,
        b => SI,
        sel => SE,
        y => mux_d);

    mem_cell: flip_flopD_m port map(
        D => mux_d,
        reset_n => clear_n,
        preset_n => '1',
        clk => clk,
        enable => enable,
        Q => Q);
end Structural;
```

Omit flip flop, multiplexer and RCA codes for simplicity

When I synthesize(using Xilinx tool ISE), it gives me back this warning:

```
WARNING:HDLCompiler:946 - "ripple_carry_clocked_m.vhd" Line 84: Actual   for formal port d is neither a static name nor a globally static expression
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <IST_SCAN_CHAIN1> is unconnected in block <ripple_carry_clocked_m>. It will be removed from the design.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <IST_RIPPLE_CARRY> is unconnected in block <ripple_carry_clocked_m>.It will be removed from the design.
```

I don't understand where I forget the connections. Can you help me please?

Comment: You might want to tell us which "line 84" gives the error. But apparently you're connecting something that isn't either a static name or a static expression (like `'1'`) to a port, and while it may or may not be legal VHDL, it's something ISE has trouble with, so best better avoided. If it's the line `D => s_overflow & s_sum,` create an intermediate signal, assign that expression to it' and connect that to the port.

Comment: @BrianDrummond line 84 is that you said. I add an intermediate signal     s_rc_out <= s_sum & s_overflow     but warning that indicate connectionless there are still

Comment: No one can help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution in Xilinx forum https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Test-in-VHDL-of-working-frequency-of-a-combinatorial-component/td-p/734768. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @BrianDrummond's approach, I am not sure if ISE supports this statement:

D => (others=>'1')

could you try replacing this with a signal that's been assigned the same value and try.

My rationale of looking at the very first block is that if it's output is not being used, the downstream logic doesn't matter.

Comment: ISE support that assignment